# PhantomJS Rasterize PDF on Azure Cloud Services Error

Tags: asp.net, pdf, azure, phantomjs, azure-cloud-services

I'm using a modified version of the rasterize.js script that comes with PhantomJS in my .Net 4.5 application to create PDF files of web pages and am running into the following error from PhantomJS (error is repeated twice, as below):

```
2014-06-10T23:22:34 [CRITICAL] QWin32PrintEngine::initialize: OpenPrinter failed (The RPC server is unavailable.)
2014-06-10T23:22:34 [CRITICAL] QWin32PrintEngine::initialize: OpenPrinter failed (The RPC server is unavailable.)
```

It runs perfectly locally and in an Azure VM, but not as a web role on Azure Cloud Services.  Is there a configuration I need to make this work?  I know that it requires GDI and that Azure Cloud Services are supposed to support that, but is there something else I am missing?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Have this same issue on one of our servers